# Generate QR Code with CIQRCodeDescriptor initWithPayload: symbolVersion: maskPattern errorCorrectionLevel:

Tags: qr-code, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to generate a QR Code using CoreImage.
I want to be able to control the symbol version, the masking pattern, and the error correction level.

Using the simple "CIFilter filterWithName:" does not give you the ability to set the symbol version or the mask pattern.

The only way it seems possible is to use a CIQRCodeDescriptor - using "CIQRCodeDesciptor initWithPayload: symbolVersion: maskPattern: errorCorrectionLevel:"

Has anyone been able to use this method to successfully generate a QR Code image?

If so, can you please post a simple complete example?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use `CIQRCodeDescriptor` you need

- codewords (mode + character count + data + terminator + padding)
- correct symbol version (version for the character count; 1-40)
- correct mask pattern (mask with minimum penalty; 0-7)

Follows example of "Think Different".

[image: Think Different]

Notice the extra bits in codeword

- Think Different: 54 68 69 6E 6B 20 44 69 66 66 65 72 65 6E 74
- Codeword:   40 F5 46 86 96 E6 B2 04 46 96 66 66 57 26 56 E7 40 EC 11

The codeword construction is explained at [nayuiki](https://www.nayuki.io/page/creating-a-qr-code-step-by-step) or at the bottom.

```
let codeword : [UInt8] = [0x40, 0xf5, 0x46, 0x86, 0x96, 0xe6, 0xb2, 0x04, 0x46, 0x96, 0x66, 0x66, 0x57, 0x26, 0x56, 0xe7, 0x40, 0xec, 0x11]
let data = Data(bytes: codeword, count: codeword.count)
if let descriptor = CIQRCodeDescriptor(payload: data, symbolVersion: 1, maskPattern: 4, errorCorrectionLevel: .levelL) {
    if let image = imageFromBarcodeCodeDescriptor(descriptor)?.transformed(by: .init(scaleX: 10, y: 10)) {
        let newImage = NSImage()
        newImage.addRepresentation(NSCIImageRep(ciImage: image))
        imageView1.image = newImage
    }
}

func imageFromBarcodeCodeDescriptor(_ descriptor: CIBarcodeDescriptor) -> CIImage? {
    let filter =  CIFilter(name: "CIBarcodeGenerator", parameters: ["inputBarcodeDescriptor" : descriptor])
    return filter?.outputImage
}
```

[image: codeword construction]

> 3. Concatenate segments, add padding, make codewords
>
> Notes:
>
> The segment mode is always a 4-bit field.
>
> The character count’s field width depends on the mode and version.
>
> The terminator is normally four “0” bits, but fewer if the data
> codeword capacity is reached.
>
> The bit padding is between zero to seven “0” bits, to fill all unused
> bits in the last byte.
>
> The byte padding consists of alternating (hexadecimal) EC and 11 until
> the capacity is reached.
>
> The entire sequence of data bits:
> 01000000111101010100011010000110100101101110011010110010000001000100011010010110011001100110011001010111001001100101011011100111010000001110110000010001
>
> The entire sequence of data codeword bytes (by splitting the bit
> string into groups of 8 bits), displayed in hexadecimal: 40 F5 46 86
> 96 E6 B2 04 46 96 66 66 57 26 56 E7 40 EC 11

Answer (score 0):

It seems `CIQRCodeGenerator` doesn't support those parameters.
Maybe you can find what you are looking for in [this library](https://github.com/EFPrefix/EFQRCode/blob/master/USERGUIDE.md).

Comment: Yes, CIQRCodeGenerator does not support these parameters, however, CIQRCodeDescriptor is SUPPOSED to but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `CIQRCodeDescriptor` _does_ contain those parameters, but you can't use it to generate codes. It's for retrieving code information when _detecting_ codes with Vision.

Comment: Looking at the library you posted also doesn't seem to allow for the control of the symbol version or masking patter. But thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "CIBarcodeGenerator" CIFilter with the CIQRCodeDescriptor  as input:

```
let data = ... // error corrected payload data

if let barcode = CIQRCodeDescriptor(payload: data,
                                 symbolVersion: 1, // 1...40
                                 maskPattern: 0, // 0..7
                                 errorCorrectionLevel: .levelL) // Any of the available enum values
{
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIBarcodeGenerator",
                          parameters: ["inputBarcodeDescriptor": barcode])

    let image = filter?.outputImage
}
```

The caveat though is that you need to obtain somehow the errorCorrectedPayload data for the message you are trying to encode. One of the ways to do this would be to use "CIQRCodeGenerator" to encode the message, parse the resulting image with Vision to extract the barcode descriptor from it, and then get the errorCorrectedPayload data from that descriptor.

Answer (score -2):

A simple working example is:

```
// Create the CIFilter (CIQRCodeGenerator)
CIFilter *ciFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
[ciFilter setDefaults];
NSData *data = [@"123456" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];// QR code value
[ciFilter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];
[ciFilter setValue:@"L" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];// L: low, M: Medium, Q: Quartile, H: High

// Create the image at the desired size
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(280, 280);// Desired QR code size
CGRect rect = CGRectIntegral(ciFilter.outputImage.extent);
CIImage *ciImage = [ciFilter.outputImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(size.width/CGRectGetWidth(rect), size.height/CGRectGetHeight(rect))];

// Create a UIImage (if needed)
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage];
_imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not allow for the symbol version or the masking pattern to be set.

Comment: This is not answer to question which requires symbol & mask